# What does it mean when there are two letters in the subscript next to a variable inside a summation equation?

Tags: calculus, matrices, optimization, summation, education

What does it mean when I have multiple subscripts inside a summation equation?

I have a formula with a summation equation that iterates over weekdays (i) and over device types (phone, tablet, desktop) (j). Inside theres a variable cost. Cost has this subsript: ij. What does ij mean?

I'll follow with an example and a screenshot to the formula

1. Is it the sum of the their cost?
2. Is it the product of their cost?
3. Or is it more like the sum of a filter

Example Phone (10€), Monday (20€), Phone on Mondays (3€)

1. 10€+20€=30€
2. 10€*20€=200€
3. Of the 20€ of Mondays 3€ are Phones (and/or) Of the 10€ of phones, 3€ are Mondays

[Picture of the equation - what does cost ij mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m52Jy.png)

Comment: The cost of device $i$ on day $j$.

Comment: In more words, we can have sequences like so: $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4,\dots$ which can be thought of as one-dimensional arrays.  Similarly we can have two-dimensional arrays such as $\begin{array}{c}a_{1,1}&a_{1,2},&a_{1,3}&\dots\\a_{2,1}&a_{2,2}&a_{2,3}&\dots\\a_{3,1}\\\vdots\end{array}$ and even higher dimensional arrays.  You can think of it as a function of however many variables, here $\text{cost}_{i,j}$ (*when both are indexvariable names and not numbers the comma might be omitted*) is $c(i,j)$ where $c$ is the function mapping device,day pairs to the cost of that device on that day.

Comment: You ended so many of my headaches. Thank you1